# Is it a security vulnerabity to pass all field values of a record to a user

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, security

I created a Apex class that returns every field of a context record into any flow. The program works with any sObject.

Are there any security vulnerabilities by doing this? Should I prevent fields that a context user doesn't have access to from populating? Because, in theory, couldn't a context user just view a field they dont have access to by creating a flow that displays the value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To return all details regardless of permissions would be inappropriate, for sure, were to user able to access these values without the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the user can run the flow client-side, such as a screen flow, this would be rejected in a Security Review, since it exposes data the user should potentially not be able to see. If it was a server-side flow, like a record-triggered flow, then there'd be less of a risk. Regardless, as a best practice, you should, at minimum, use `Security.stripInaccessible` to prevent data leaks that may be considered a security risk.